# Azure purview remove multiple assets at a time using API

Tags: api, azure-purview

I am a collection admin of a purview account , and  there is thousands of asset in a collection . and now I would like to delete the assets inside the collection .

how can I do that in bulk ( because there is no GUI method ) . How can I achieve that ?

I want to authen the API (purview API) using my AAD account which login to the purview .

Please help and advice . Better to use power shell or bash(Azure cloud) Thanks

Comment: anyone has the idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using PyApacheAtlas?  A delete operation across many assets can be as simple as this [delete sample](https://github.com/wjohnson/pyapacheatlas/blob/master/samples/CRUD/delete_entity.py).

```py
client = PurviewClient(
        account_name = os.environ.get("PURVIEW_NAME", ""),
        authentication=oauth
)

# When you know the GUID that you want to delete
response = client.delete_entity(guid="123-abc-456-def")
print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))

# When you need to find multiple Guids to delete and they all
# are the same type
entities = client.get_entity(
qualifiedName=["qualifiedname1", "qualifiedname2", "qualifiedname3"],
    typeName="my_type"
)

# This is a naive approach and it would be better to batch
# the delete into groups of say 100
for entity in entities.get("entities"):
    guid = entity["guid"]
    delete_response = client.delete_entity(guid=guid)
    print(json.dumps(delete_response, indent=2))
```

Ultimately, if you don't know the guids, you'll need to fetch the entities based on [searching for them](https://github.com/wjohnson/pyapacheatlas/blob/master/samples/CRUD/identify_assets_to_delete_by_fqn.py) or using the fully qualified name and type to get the entity and then retrieve their guid.

This can be accomplished via the Purview REST API as well using:

- [Delete by Unique Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/delete-by-unique-attribute?tabs=HTTP)
- [Get by Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/get-by-guid?tabs=HTTP) or [Get by Unique Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/get-by-unique-attributes?tabs=HTTP)
- [Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/discovery/query?tabs=HTTP) for searching for qualified names

Comment: Do you happen to know how we can use `PyApacheAtlas` to read from a list of assets from an `Excel` file and delete those assets.. If you have time to comment or suggest a solution, I have posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76285715/1232087)