# Delete multiple assets of Microsoft Purview using REST API

Tags: python, azure-rest-api, azure-purview, apache-atlas

We did a `Purview Scan` of an `Azure SQL Database`. Now many of the SQL tables have been dropped from the database. But those assets (tables in Purview) are still in `Purview`. We want to delete those assets using a `REST API`.

Using [PyApacheAtlas](https://github.com/wjohnson/pyapacheatlas), a delete operation across many assets can be as simple as this [delete sample](https://github.com/wjohnson/pyapacheatlas/blob/master/samples/CRUD/delete_entity.py).

**Question**: If we have an `EXCEL` file with a list of assets with their corresponding `DUIDs`, is there a way to read that list and delete the assets using the sample code in link 2 above. The link 1 above talks about doing some bulk upload operations using an EXCEL file. I was wondering how can we achive the same for bulk delete of assets of same types. Something similar is explained [here](https://datasmackdown.com/oss/pyapacheatlas/excel/bulk-upload.html). But I've not been able to simulate the same for bulk delete. Maybe, someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to delete multiple assets from the catalog is through REST APIs.

Steps to delete an Asset in Purview using REST API:

From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/tutorial-using-rest-apis), follow the steps to Use the Postman client to call the REST APIs.

**Step1:**  Get Token

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-tenant-id>/oauth2/token
```

[image]

**Step2:** How to find a guid of an asset in Azure Purview Studio. Select any asset and you will find the guid in the url section:

[image]

**Step3:** [Entity - Delete By Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/delete-by-guid) – Used to delete single asset by using associated Guid:

Syntax: `DELETE {Endpoint}/catalog/api/atlas/v2/entity/guid/{guid}`

Sample URL: `DELETE {Endpoint}/catalog/api/atlas/v2/entity/guid/fd279eb4-f6c3-1b0b-ad67-e4f8abd2972f`

**Step4:** [Entity - Delete By Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/delete-by-guids?tabs=HTTP)s – Used to delete mulitple asset by using associated Guid:

Syntax: `DELETE {Endpoint}/catalog/api/atlas/v2/entity/bulk?guids={guids}`

Sample:

```
DELETE {Endpoint}/catalog/api/atlas/v2/entity/bulk?guids=[  
      
      "18e06957-e265-967a-07f1-e14e2ab8940f",  
      
      "cc0730ba-9b30-41f0-6953-559d17626d2b"  
      
    ]
```

For more details, refer to [MS Q&A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/805790/delete-multiple-assets-in-purview) addressing similar issue,